# Absolute Value Semantics

Tags: calculus

Spivak's definition of the **absolute value**  $\left| a \right|$ of $a$ is:
$$\left| a \right| = \begin{cases}
 a, \quad a \geq 0 \\ 
 -a, \quad a \leq 0
\end{cases}$$

He adds:

> Note that $\left| a \right|$ is always positive, except when $a = 0$

Now, most definitions on the "great" 'interwebs' :-) are the same, except for one subtle difference. For example, here is the Khan Academy definition.

$$\left| a \right| = \begin{cases}
 a, \quad a \geq 0 \\ 
 -a, \quad a < 0
\end{cases}$$

Spivak says that $0$ is not positive, but does his definition not lead to ambiguity? Am I just nitpicking, or is there something that I am missing here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: When specifying definitions by cases, I prefer them to be mutually exclusive, but I suppose what Spivak does is harmless, since what's more important is that (1) the overlapping portions aren't contradictory, and (2) the cases are exhaustive.  Tangentially related: [$|x|$ versus $\pm x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230325/21813)

Comment: I think there is no ambiguity here, as the first definition says the exception. You can simply say the absolute value is always non-negative.

Comment: Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally prefer the second one but the two definitions are equivalent since

$$|a|=0 \iff a=0 \iff -a=0$$

and there is not ambiguity also with the first one.

Comment: So, just that I understand, this means that if the absolute value of $a$ were $0$, then by Spivak's definition $|a|$ could be either $a$ or $-a$, but because both equal $0$ and because of $0$'s unique properties, this is "harmless" as pointed out in a comment above.

Comment: @user1115542 Yes in the case $a=0$ we have $|a|=a=-a=0$ and both definition are fine.

Comment: Thank you very much.