# Question about absolute value definition from my textbook

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, definition, absolute-value

I just want to know if there is a mistake in my text book.

The proof from my textbook is as follows:

> For any real number $a \in \mathbb{R} $ we have $-\lvert a \rvert \leq a \leq \lvert a \rvert$.
>
> *Proof*. [...] When $a < 0$ then $a < 0 < \lvert a \rvert $, showing that $a \leq \lvert a \rvert$, while $-\lvert a \rvert = -(-a) = a$ [...]

I don't understand the last part regarding $-\lvert a \rvert = -(-a) = a $.

If $ a = -4 $, for example, would it not be $-\lvert -4 \rvert = -\lvert 4 \rvert = -4$?

Comment: Do you disagree that $-|a|$, $-(-a)$, and $a$ are all equal when $a=-4$?

Comment: There’s no mistake in the book.

Comment: Maybe helpful: [definition and discussion of absolute value](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230325/21813)

Comment: @EricWofsey thought that −|a| = -4 and that −(−a) = 4 when a=−4. So, yes, I don't really understand why they are all equal.

Comment: "−(−a) = 4 when a=−4": When $a=-4,$ we have $-|a| = -|-4| = -4$ and $-(-a) = -(--4) = -(+4) = -4.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes, I thought about adding this to the answer, but I didn't think it was possible that the OP's problem was $4=-(-4)$. Maybe, that was a problem..

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave does not contradict the book and the book is correct.

---

If $a<0$, then

$$-\lvert a \rvert = -(-a) = a $$

This is correct by definition of absolute value. Because,

$$|a|=a, \thinspace a≥0\iff -|a|=-a$$

For $ a = -4 $, you wrote

$$-\lvert -4 \rvert = -\lvert 4 \rvert = -4$$

That is correct. But, note that here we don't need to write  $|4|$ here. Because, $|-4|=4$ by definition of absolute value. Thus, we can write

$$-|-4|=-4$$

---

By definition of absolute value we can also write,

$$|a|≥a ~~\text{and}~~ |a|≥-a$$

This immediately implies, we have

$$-|a|≤a≤|a|.$$

---

This comes from,

$$\begin{align}&a≥0\\
\iff &-a≤0≤a\\
\iff &|a|=a≥a≥-a\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}&a<0\\
\iff&-a>0>a\\
\iff& |a|=-a≥-a>a.\end{align} $$

Comment: I'll update my answer if I know the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but minor possible improvements: **(1)** Maybe say "true" instead of "correct", since "correct" has a slight connotation of being an assertion about the proof (a meta notion) rather than of being an assertion about a formal mathematical statement within the proof. **(2)** "If $a = -4 $, then $-\lvert -4 \rvert = -\lvert 4 \rvert = -4$" Note that $-\lvert -4 \rvert = -\lvert 4 \rvert = -4$ is true regardless of the value of $a,$ so you probably don't want to write this as an "if ... then" statement. **(continued)**

Comment: Instead, you probably intended to say something like "For example, substituting $-4$ for $a$ in the previous equality gives ..." **(3)** You should probably avoid notation such as $a \geq \pm a$ in an explanation like this in which part of the OPs problem might be interpreting symbolic statements. **(4)** Overall, I would probably start with the definition of absolute value, noting that removal of absolute value bars involves two sign cases, and thus the subsequent analysis breaks down into two sign cases, $\ldots$ (I'll return several hours later $\ldots$ need to leave now.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I added points.