# Is my process of doing this math accurate?

Tags: notation, convention

**Problem:**

Find the points of trisection of the line segment AB, where $A\equiv(4,0), B\equiv(0,3)$

**Process 1:**

Let the P & Q be the points of trisection. Let $x_1$ & $y_1$ be the abscissa and ordinate of P, and let $x_2$ & $y_2$ be the abscissa and ordinate of Q. Now,

$$(x_1,y_1)=\left(\frac{(2)(4)+(1)(0)}{3},\frac{(2)(0)+(1)(3)}{3}\right)$$

$$=\left(\frac{8}{3}, 1\right)$$

$$...$$

**Process 2:**

Let the P & Q be the points of trisection. Let $x_1$ & $y_1$ be the abscissa and ordinate of P, and let $x_2$ & $y_2$ be the abscissa and ordinate of Q. Now,

$$(x_1,y_1)\equiv\left(\frac{(2)(4)+(1)(0)}{3},\frac{(2)(0)+(1)(3)}{3}\right)$$

$$\equiv\left(\frac{8}{3}, 1\right)\tag{1}$$

$$...$$

**Question:**

1. Should I use the $=$ sign or the $\equiv$ sign?
2. If process 2 is correct, then in line $(1)$ should I use $=$ or $\equiv$ before $\left(\frac{8}{3}, 1\right)$? Currently, there is an $\equiv$ before $\left(\frac{8}{3}, 1\right)$ in line $(1)$.

**Comments:**

The usage of $=$ in process 1 seems completely fine to me. However, in my book, it has been written like process 2. So, am I correct to write in process 1?

Comment: @ryang "Are the differences between the two "processes" just the two ≡ symbols instead of two = symbols?": yes sir. "And are you asking whether, in each instance, ≡ or = is more appropriate?": yes sir.

Comment: There’s no reason to use the [identity symbol](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254850/21813) here. Your ‘equals’ sign is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol $≡$ has multiple meanings in mathematics, to indicate a definition, a mathematical or logical equivalence between two statements, an equivalence relation (like in modular arithmetic, and congruence of geometric figures), an [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254850/21813) (an equation like $x^2-y^2≡(x+y)(x-y)$ that is true for every allowable combination of variable values), etc.

In your quoted example, there is no compelling reason to switch $=$ and $≡.$ The latter is just confusing here, unless the author has prefaced it with a note on *their* particular usage of $≡.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had another question: why are points denoted using the identity sign always? Example: $A\equiv(0,10)$

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic They're not, typically. But if your text does this, it is probably *defining* point $A$ as $(0,10).$ You could also write $A:=(0,10)$ to indicate a definition/declaration.  But all this may be a little pompous. Check out this [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4230325/21813) in which, for differerent emphases, I'd used all three symbols.